# Manipulating the html elements inside the view which is inside the src of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, iframe

I have an iframe inside a view and in the src of the iframe I am rendering another view. Now I want to get the data of header h2 which is having some id and is present inside the second view rendered inside the src of the iframe.
Please help me out with your ideas and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples to access your iframe document:

```
var frame = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentDocument; // first iframe in page
// or
var frame = window.frames["myFrame"].document; // if your frame has the name "myFrame"
// or
var frame = document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.document; // if your frame has the id "myFrame"
```

Then you can access your H2 tag inside the iframe with:

```
 var h2 = frame.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0];
```

jQuery solution:

```
 var frame = $("selector").contents(); // where selector is "#myFrameID" or ".myFrameClass", etc...
 var h2 = frame.find("h2");
```

Comment: Although I already did it but your jquery solution matches perfectly with what I did. I just added an extra .html() at the end.
Thanks for your answer. I will mark it

Comment: Although I already did it but your jquery solution matches perfectly with what I did. I just added an extra .html() at the end.